# How to enable user_can_rich_edit for guests?

Tags: visual-editor

Using wp 3.3beta1 with the wp_editor on the front-end for bbPress.

When calling the editor on the front end, how do I allow a guest to see the visual editor?

I only see options to disable the visual editor site wide, or on a per user basis, but no option to allow guests to use visual?

Comment: Considering this is a feature of a pre-release version of WP that's still in development ... I doubt you're going to get much traction in the short term.  Most of the people here haven't even *heard* of `wp_editor()`, let alone used it enough to offer advice ...

Comment: Yeah, that is why I have been posting these editor questions on a few sites in the hopes that someone else has tried playing around with the editor/rich edit. The alpha/beta wordpress support forum is pretty much a ghost town. Also trying to get some of these questions out there in the hopes that devs see them prior to release of 3.3, otherwise it's gonna be months before it's ready to use. It is VERY close right now to being fully usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `can_richedit` capability to the user you want to be able to use the editor.

You can use the [Capability Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/) to do it.

**Update:** to enable the rich editor on anonymous/guest users, add this to your `funcitons.php` or anywhere you like, just make sure it comes before the `wp_editor()` call.

```
add_filter('user_can_richedit', '__return_true');
```

Comment: I am asking for can_richedit for guests which actually have no role or capability set.

Comment: Why would you show an editor to a guest (ie not-registered) user?

Comment: I am using the bbPress forums plugin which has the option of allowing guests to post topics and replies without logging in. Normally bbPress uses a simple textarea input but I replaced that box with the wp_editor, hence the need for guests can richedit. This issue is going to be coming up a lot once people realize we can now use the editor on the front end. (can even use it for comments, so another reason to allow guests to richedit) Hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: I understand, updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: thank you, it worked. Can you think of any 'security' related reasons why not to do this? I'm guessing the richeditor takes care of security for user input, but not sure.

Comment: If the field posted is handled by WordPress you are safe, the contents will be run trough `esc_textarea()`.